# Postman Prerequest Scripts keep getting "ReferenceError: [variablename] is not defined" but use pm.variables.set as defined

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

OK.  I have been reading the Postman docs and looking at various posted examples but I cannot seem to be able to have the Postman web or windows app (v8.8.0) utilize the .set functions effectively to establish and update variables as I always get the following:

```
ReferenceError: [variablename] is not defined"
```

Here are my simple test prerequest script and variables defined that I have tried at different scopes in prerequest scripts:

Example 1) Local Variable

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
pm.variables.set("randomVal",random);
console.log(randomVal);
```

> Result: ReferenceError: randomVal is not defined

> Expected: {random > number up to 10}

Example 2) Environment Variable

```
pm.environment.set("enviro_variable_key", "enviro_variable_value");
pm.environment.get("enviro_variable_key");
console.log(enviro_variable_key);
```

> ReferenceError: enviro_variable_key is not defined

> Expected: enviro_variable_value

Example 3)

```
pm.globals.set("global_variable_key", "global_variable_value");
pm.globals.get("global_variable_key");
console.log(global_variable_key);
```

> Result: ReferenceError: global_variable_key is not defined

> Expected: global_variable_value

Example 4)

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("collection_var_key", "collection_var_value")
pm.collectionVariables.get("collection_var_key");
console.log(collection_var_key);
```

> Result: ReferenceError: collection_var_key is not defined

> Expected: collection_var_value

---

Any clarification or help - or see if these simple prerequest scripts work on your system - would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a scoped variable and then trying to read a local variable, which isn't defined.

The syntax you need would be this:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set('collection_var_key', 'some_collection_variable');
console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get('collection_var_key');
```